# AngularJS controller inheritance in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, ecmascript-6

I've got project in AngularJS and I have `baseController` and child controller inheriting from it.

```
class BaseController {
    constructor($log, $state) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$log = $log;
        this.$state = $state;
    }
}

class ChildController extends BaseController {

    constructor(myService) {
        'ngInject';

        super();
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

My question is: Do I need to inject all parent dependency injections into child controller even when I am not using it?

Above example shows what I want to achieve, but it's not working. Anyone got idea if I can achieve it without passing BaseController services into `super($scope, $state)` invocation?

Comment: Why do you not use `super($scope,$state)` ?

Comment: I need to inject them twice. First time in child constructor and pass it to super to `BaseController`, which already have these injected. Seems redundant to me. For now I did `super($scope, $state)`, but I want to know if is there a better way? doing it for 2 injections is ok, but when I have ~7 or more it is a bit of work to correct DI in parent and every child class.

Comment: Class based controllers should avoid injecting `$scope`. Common functions should be moved to services instead of extending controller classes.

Comment: $scope is just an example. Let's pretend instead of scope, there is my custom service (for example `AuthenticationService`).

Comment: The [$injector Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) only injects dependencies into the constructor function of the instantiated class. It does not inject into construction functions of ancestor classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [$injector Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) only injects dependencies into the constructor function of the instantiated class. It does not inject into construction functions of ancestor classes.

To construct a controller with injectables from an ancestor class, use the [$injector service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) and [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend):

```
class BaseController {
    constructor($log, $window) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$log = $log;
        this.$window = $window;
    }
}

class ChildController  ̶e̶x̶t̶e̶n̶d̶s̶ ̶B̶a̶s̶e̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶ {

    constructor(myService, $injector) {
        'ngInject';
        var base = $injector.instantiate(BaseController);
        angular.extend(this, base);
        ̶s̶u̶p̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    $onInit() {
      this.$log.info("$onInit");
      this.$log.log(this.base);
    }
}
```

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gMDvP5YlYex1apRlVWyG?p=preview)

```js
class BaseController {
    constructor($log, $window) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$log = $log;
        this.$window = $window;
        this.base = "Hello from BaseController";
    }
}

class ChildController {

    constructor(myService, $injector) {
        'ngInject';
        var base = $injector.instantiate(BaseController);
        angular.extend(this, base);
        //super();
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    $onInit() {
      this.$log.info("$onInit");
      this.$log.log(this.base);
    }
}

angular.module("app",[])
.controller("child", ChildController)
.value("myService", {})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="child as vm">
    {{vm.base}}
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, works well for my case, but it looks a bit hacky (not complaining) ;)